# Can I watch() the elements within a v-for separately?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, watch, v-for

I have `v-for="pill in pills"` loop that creates a set of panels, each of these panels includes a number that can be changed (either through +/- buttons or by directly editing them). All of the panels are in an Array of Objects (one of the properties of these Objects is that amount)

I would like to react when the amount changes in one of the panels (and make an HTTP call). Today I do that by watching the whole Array:

```
watch(() => pills.value, () => console.log('a pill changed'), { deep: true })
```

This is not practical, though, because I have to send all the objects one by one through the HTTP call above because I do not know which of them changed.

It would be great if I could somehow `watch()` each of the `pill` separately, and act upon changes on specific ones (i.e. send only the one that changed). Is this possible?

Comment: It seems you can achieve this without using `watch` but first, can you include your code here?

Answer (score 0):

this is a very common problem, the core team is solving in front of you can only use my way:

```js
// </script><script type="module">
import { ref, watch } from "https://esm.run/vue@3"

const pills = ref([0])

function onChangeItem(i, newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log("index %i changed value %s -> %s", i, oldVal, newVal)
}

const watchers = new Map()
watch(() => pills.value.length, (newLength, $oldLength, onCleanup) => {
  const oldLength = $oldLength ?? 0
  if (newLength > oldLength) {
    for (let i = oldLength; i < newLength; i++) {
      watchers.set(i, watch(() => pills.value[i], (n, o) => {
        onChangeItem(i, n, o)
      }, { immediate: $oldLength !== undefined }))
    }
    return
  }
  if (newLength < oldLength) {
    for (let i = newLength; i < oldLength; i++) {
      watchers.get(i)?.()
      watchers.delete(i)
    }
  }
}, { immediate: true })

async function main() {
pills.value[0] += 10

await Promise.resolve()
pills.value.push(20)

await Promise.resolve()
pills.value.pop()
pills.value.pop()
}

main()
```

> Note: that this is an unoptimized version of the cleanup you have to add `onBeforeUnmount(() => watchers.forEach(item => item()))` or something to cancel if the `Effect listener` end of life

Answer (score -3):

eg 1

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            obj:{
                a:''
            },
        },
        watch:{
            /
            'obj.a'(item1,item2){
                
            },
            deep:true
        }
    }
</script>
```

eg 2

```
<template>
    <div></div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            newArr:[
                {
                    list:[
                        {
                            label:null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        methods:{
            show(){
                this.newArr[0].list[0].label = "2020年11月10日10:36:58";
            }
        },
        watch:{
            newArr:{
                handler(val){
                    // ...
                },
                deep:true
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**